# ForEach loop results in a single HTML table

Tags: powershell

Below is a simplified version of a code I use to check different folders, check the most recent log file, and then report the most recent 3 timestamps (denoted by `[`).

```
$LogLocations = "C:\Powershell\Test\Scenario1",
                "C:\Powershell\Test\Scenario2"

$style = @"
<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}
TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }
TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
</style>
"@

$body = ""

foreach ($logpath in $LogLocations) {
    $log  = Get-ChildItem -Path $logpath |
            sort LastWriteTime |
            select -ExpandProperty FullName -Last 1
    $text = Get-Content -Path $log |
            Select-String -SimpleMatch "[" |
            select Line -Last 3
    $body += ($text |
             select Line |
             ConvertTo-Html -Body "<p>Timestamps of 3 most recent files processed $log</p>" -Head $style |
             Out-String)
}

$emailbody = ConvertTo-Html -PostContent $body | Out-String
$subject = "Processing Logs Error Checking at " + (Get-Date -Format g)

Send-MailMessage -From "xxxxxxxxx" -To "xxxxxxxxx" -Subject $subject -Body $emailbody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer "xxxxxxxxx"
```

The result I get is:

```
Timestamps of 3 most recent files processed C:\Powershell\Test\Scenario1\20160520163102.txt
*
[05/21/2016 00:37:52]
[05/21/2016 00:37:52]
[05/21/2016 00:37:52]
Timestamps of 3 most recent files processed C:\Powershell\Test\Scenario2\20160524142045.txt
*
[05/24/2016 14:38:48]
[05/24/2016 14:38:51]
[05/24/2016 14:38:51]
```

which is fine. I get the info I want, it's just that the formatting isn't the greatest. I've tried to find a way to put the results in the same table, but cannot get the code to work, I will either get errors, no results, or horribly formatted results.

Any ideas? I was going down the route of nesting the current `foreach` statement inside another `foreach` statement for table columns.

Comment: This is great, but can you mock up an visual example of what you would like it to look like while it's displayed 'in the same table,' as you describe?  That will help ensure the answers are exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want multiple tables, don't create multiple tables.

```
$emailbody = $LogLocations | ForEach-Object {
    $dir = $_
    Get-ChildItem $dir |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
        Select-Object -Last 1 |
        Get-Content |
        Where-Object { $_ -like '*[*' } |
        Select-Object -Last 3 @{n='File';e={$dir.FullName}},
            @{n='Timestamp';e={$_}}
} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
```

Comment: Does the `Get-Content` command require a path?

`cmdlet Get-Content at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]: `

That is the response I get.

Comment: My mistake. There was supposed to be a `|` after `Select-Object -Last 1`. Fixed.